# Image size in other state

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml, flash-builder

i have this source in flex - easy program which switch between two states..in second state is show myImage component

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
               xmlns:components="components.*">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                if (currentState == "state1")
                    currentState = "state2";
                else
                    currentState = "state1";                        
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="state1" />
        <s:State name="state2" />
    </s:states>

    <components:myImage includeIn="state2"/>

    <s:Button label="switch states" click="button1_clickHandler(event)" />
</s:Application>
```

component myImage is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" >
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function img_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                trace("image width " + img.width);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <mx:Image id="img" source="obr.jpg" creationComplete="img_creationCompleteHandler(event)"/>
</s:Group>
```

if the same code as myImage.mxml put to main application then trace print correct value..but now when i click to button and switch to state2 then trace print width as 0..why? after which event is image in state2 loaded and i can use image.width property??

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't have a width is because your image isn't loaded yet.  It still needs to get the image from your server to work.  There are two thing you can do.  You can embed the image so that on `creationComplete` the image is already there (to embed, just do `@Embed('image.jpg')` for the source), or wait for the image to load using the `complete` event, but then it's not 100% that your container (Image) will resize right away. You can try doing a `callLater` for your trace.  Try debugging and check for `contentWidth` property on the image, that might be a better property to use since it relates to the image itself, not the container.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `itemCreationPolicy="immediate"` to the image the following way:

```
<components:myImage includeIn="state2" itemCreationPolicy="immediate" />
```

Comment: when i add this property to compoment (as you write) trace still print width as 0 :(

Comment: Try to use `complete` event instead of `creationComplete` event: `<mx:Image id="img" source="obr.jpg" complete="img_creationCompleteHandler(event)"/>`

Comment: afraid, trace still print only 0 :(

Comment: when i add to compoment myImage any button and after this button click event print same trace, so print correct width...but i need do it automaticly..

Comment: Don't force image creation. Bad standards to force creation of objects before they're needed.

Comment: Ok, try to use `contentWidth` property to trace instead of `width`.

Comment: Agreed with @J_A_X about avoiding using `itemCreationPolicy="immediate"`